# Need help building billiards game in Processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to figure out how to make the black ball, labeled bBall in this case, to move in the direction it was hit from the white ball (wBall), and then disappear if it hits one of the side or corner pockets, how might i go about accomplishing this?

```
ball wBall, bBall;
int click;
String msg;
Boolean moving = false;
int difx, dify;
float cdistance;
int steps = 20;
void setup(){
   click=0;
   size(800,400);
   background(16,77,27);
   wBall = new ball(35,#ffffff);
   bBall = new ball(35,#000000);
   msg="";
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(!moving){
 click++; 
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(16,77,27);
  String msg;
  fill(0,0,0);
 ellipse(15,15,30,30); 
 ellipse(785,15,30,30);
 ellipse(15,385,30,30);
 ellipse(785,385,30,30);
 ellipse(410,15,30,30);
 ellipse(410,385,30,30);
 msg="the click count is "+click;
 println("the click count is "+click);
 //Moving Balls\\
 fill(255,255,255);
 noStroke();  
 bBall.xpos=(250);
 bBall.ypos=height/2;
 bBall.update();
 if(click==0){
  wBall.xpos=mouseX;
  wBall.ypos=mouseY;
 }else if(click==1){
   difx = wBall.xpos-bBall.xpos;
   dify = wBall.ypos-bBall.ypos;
 }else if(click==2){
  cdistance = dist(wBall.xpos,wBall.ypos,bBall.xpos,bBall.ypos);
   if (cdistance>bBall.ballDiam/2){
    moving = true;
    wBall.xpos-=difx/steps;
    wBall.ypos-=dify/steps;
   }else{
      moving = false;
      wBall.visible=false;
      click=3;
   } 
 }
 wBall.update();
}

class ball{
  int xpos, ypos;
  color myColor;
  int ballDiam;
  boolean visible = true;
  ball(int tempdiam, color tempColor){
    myColor=tempColor;
    ballDiam=tempdiam;
  }

   void update(){
   if(visible){
    fill(myColor);
    ellipse(xpos,ypos,ballDiam,ballDiam);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will make things easier if you break up your inquiry into multiple questions, instead of saying "fix my game"... So work until you stumble upon something you can not solve and then ask (for that specific thing) here, get an answer, and start the same process again.

The ball is moving with your mouse properly but is leaving a trail. That is because you are not drawing the background with each loop. What happens is that each time you call draw(), the canvas is filled over the previous canvas. In order to avoid that just call

```
background(16,77,27);
```

right after the void draw(){ line, which will fill the canvas with whatever colour you tell it!

Comment: very helpful! thank you! and i will try to be more specific with my next question!